# Correct way to manage inheritance

Tags: java, oop

Current I have code like this:

```
public void processAnimal(Animal a){
    if (a instanceof Cat){
        processCat((Cat)a);
    } else if (a instanceof Dog){
        processDog((Dog)a);
    } else if (a instanceof Bird){
        processBird((Bird)a);
    }
}

public void processCat(Cat c){
    ...
}

public void processDog(Dog d){
    ...
}

public void processBird(Bird b){
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to get rid of the boilerplate `if` statements?

---

Update: I have a set of models that get processed differently in different locations. Imagine each one of these are pets. A petstore may want to have a cat interact with other cats, and dogs interact with other dogs, wheras a home may want to have dogs and cats in the same locations.

So each model won't know how to interact in the given situations.

Comment: Not if you are calling methods that only exist in each subtype. If you are calling methods inherited from animal, you don't need any ifs.

Comment: Canonical description of this scenario: http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

Comment: Theoretically you can find the correct method by using Reflection API. However that would overcomplicate it a bit :). Maybe there is some library for this out there.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the `processAnimal` method in each respective subclass of `Animal` and then call it through `animal.processAnimal()`. Depending on the exact class of `animal` object, the correct method will be invoked.

```
ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
animals.add(new Dog());
animals.add(new Cat());
animals.add(new Bird());

for (Animal animal : animals) {
    animal.processAnimal();  // appropriate method for each object will be called
}
```

Comment: Updated my question. The problem is that a petstore might process a cat different than a home or vet.